# Back to the chemistry class

Tags: code-golf, chemistry

### Introduction

One of the first things I learned in chemistry, was giving the formula for the combustion of alkanes. The most basic example was: `2CH4 + 4O2 -> 4H2O + 2CO2`. **Note that the equation could have been simplified by dividing every coefficient by 2, we would get** `CH4 + 2O2 -> 2H2O + CO2`. **To make things easier, we are going to ignore this to not complicate things**.

You can see that with the combustion of any alkane, oxygen is used. After the reaction, only `CO2` and `H2O` are made.

## The task

The input will always be in the form `C(n)H(2n+2)`, with `n>0`. These are some example inputs:

```
CH4
C2H6
C3H8
C4H10
C5H12
C6H14
```

### Useful tip:

Every alkane has a standard pattern in the combustion reaction:

```
2C(n)H(2n+2) + (3n+1)O2 -> (2n+2)H2O + (2n)CO2
```

e.g.

`C4H10` gives the following equation: `2C(4)H(2*4+2) + (3*4+1)O2 -> (2*4+2)H2O + (2*4)CO2`. After calculating everything, we get this final equation `2C4H10 + 13O2 -> 10H2O + 8CO2`

### Testcases

```
CH4
2CH4 + 4O2 -> 4H2O + 2CO2

C3H8
2C3H8 + 10O2 -> 8H2O + 6CO2

C4H10
2C4H10 + 13O2 -> 10H2O + 8CO2

C12H26
2C12H26 + 37O2 -> 26H2O + 24CO2
```

## Rules

- Note that I used spaces for the examples to increase readability, **these are not necessary**. `2CH4 + 4O2 -> 4H2O + 2CO2` and `2CH4+4O2->4H2O+2CO2` are both valid outputs. However, if you *consistently* use spaces for the output, you get a **-10% bonus**
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: totally different but related: [Drawing Lewis Structures of Alkanes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64125/drawing-lewis-structures-of-alkanes)

Comment: So we can assume that the input will be correct formulas?

Comment: @TanMath, yes, you don't have to worry about invalid formulas

Comment: "consistently use spaces" - would consistently using 0 spaces count?

Comment: @Mego, no. Using 0 spaces is not using spaces at all, so the rule doesn't apply

Comment: Is C1H4 valid? Or it has to be CH4?

Comment: @Zereges, it has to be CH4

Comment: I'm disappointed at the lack of Unicode subscripts.

Comment: Is a newline character required at the end of the output?

Comment: @TomCarpenter no, that is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
s[2z\+h*3Jv|hctz\H\1"O2>"yhJ"H2O+"yJ"CO2
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B2z%5C%2Bh*3Jv%7Chctz%5CH%5C1%22O2%3E%22yhJ%22H2O%2B%22yJ%22CO2&input=C4H10&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B2z%5C%2Bh*3Jv%7Chctz%5CH%5C1%22O2%3E%22yhJ%22H2O%2B%22yJ%22CO2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=CH4%0AC2H6%0AC3H8%0AC4H10%0AC5H12%0AC6H14%0AC12H26&debug=0)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 * 0.9 = 77.4 bytes

```py
s=input()
N=int(s.split('H')[1])
print("2%s + %dO2 > %dH20 + %dCO2"%(s,N*1.5-2,N,N-2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2M6@gtERDk8sPyCrRKNYrLsjJLNFQ91DXjDaM1eQqKAIJKxmpFitoK6im@Bsp2AEpDyMDMNfZ30hJVaNYx0/LUM9U10jHT8dP10hT8/9/Z2MPCwA)

Extracts the number of `H`'s rather than the number of `C`'s from the input. This avoid special-casing `CH4` and simplifies the output expressions in terms of `N=2n+2`.

The output has parameters plugged in via string formatting. The first summand is just the input string, and the rest have calculated numbers plugged in. Note that `N*1.5-2` (same as `N*3/2-2`) gives a float, but the string formatting converts it to an int.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 202 * 0.9 = 181.8 bytes

Sometimes, I wonder if I'm just hurting myself with Java.

Thanks to @TNT and @TFeld for shaving off a good 20 bytes!

```java
class A{public static void main(String[]a){String s=a[0].substring(1,a[0].indexOf("H"));long n=Long.parseLong((s.length()>0)?s:"1");System.out.printf("2%s + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2",a[0],3*n+1,2*n+2,2*n);}}
```

Pretty simple. Basically, I cut the input from `C` to `H`, and get that substring. If it's nothing, I set `n` to one. Otherwise, I set it to the number between `C` and `H`. The code following just prints it out and puts it into proper notation.

Ungolfed

```java
class A{
    public static void main(String[]a) {
         String s=a[0].substring(1,a[0].indexOf("H"));
         long n=Long.parseLong((s.length()>0)?s:"1");
         System.out.printf("2%s + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2",a[0],3*n+1,2*n+2,2*n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but you must use STDIN and not command line args. Though you could shorten it by using `printf` instead of `+` (-11 from your raw score if I counted correctly).

Comment: [I've been told that using command line arguments is an acceptable alternative to STDIN.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25575783#25575783) Also, could you clarify how you mean for me to use `printf`? (A little finicky on that, haven't used it before. :D)

Comment: [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) uses mechanics from [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). You can have a string to print such as "%d" in your print statement and after it some value or variable that will be printed instead. It can be useful in situations where you have a lot of variables to print, [for example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55293/stop-stand-there-where-you-are/55299#55299).

Comment: And the fact that command line arguments is acceptable in place of STDIN is new (and rather helpful) news to me. :)

Comment: @TNT I've also been told that it depends on the situation as well. But, yes, it is defaultly permitted. I'm in the midst of a debate currently on whether or not it is accepted for this question specifically.

Comment: @TNT I honestly still have no idea how to use `printf`. [Can you help me with it, please?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31894/room-for-tnt-and-votetoclose)

Comment: Using `printf`:

`System.out.printf("2%s + %d2 > %d2O + %dO2",a[0],3*n+1,2*n+2,2*n);`

Comment: @TFeld Doesn't quite work - I'll use something similar, thanks. I get it now. :D

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what happened when i copied it... It seems the first letter is missing from each 'group'

Correctly should be: `System.out.printf("2%s + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2",a[0],3*n+1,2*n+2,2*n);`

Comment: @TFeld Yup, that's what I derived from it - thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you got it to work! By the way, I posted the wrong example link; I meant to post [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58199/person-of-interest/58244#58244). :P

Comment: @VoteToClose Yes, you are hurting yourself with Java.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>122</s> 91 * 0.9 = 81.9 bytes

```py
i=input()
n=2*int(i[1:i.find('H')]or 1)
print'2%s + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2'%(i,n*3/2+1,n+2,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxCoAgFEDR3a@QQNSUwtcSQS0ubn5AtEX0lpeUDX29RdPlcNOT94OgFByR0p2VZjRCjZQVzm7AZkNalQxSL8fJnWbp/J4EcXHDxRqBT18CxJ8@ghQKLdVdC8ZZMmBJl1L5LvTVCw)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 63 * 0.9 = 56.7 bytes

```javascript
_=>`2${_} + ${$=_.split`H`[1],$*1.5-2}O2 > ${$}H2O + ${$-2}CO2`
```

Similar to my ESMin answer

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 53*0.9 = 48 bytes

Previous byte count:

- 69 * 0.9 = 62
- 63 * 0.9 = 57
- 56 * 0.9 = 50

```pyth
Js>z+xz\H1s[\2z%" + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2"[-*1.5J2J-J2
```

It is just like xnor's answer, where I use the H values. A variable J is used to store the amount of H's in the molecular formula of the molecule.

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Js%3Ez%2Bxz%5CH1s%5B%5C2z%25%22+%2B+%25dO2+%3E+%25dH2O+%2B+%25dCO2%22%5B-%2a1.5J2J-J2&input=CH4&debug=0)

Comment: You spend six bytes on spacing, but gain only five bytes from the bonus, so it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/), 148 * 0.9 = 133 bytes

Prev byte counts

- 0.9*195 = 175
- 0.9*190 = 171

```py
i=raw_input()
O=3*int(i[1:i.find('H')]or 1)+1;C=2*int(i[1:i.find('H')]or 1);print"2"+i+" + "+`O`+"O2"+" > "+i[i.find('H')+1:]+"H2O"+ " + "+`C`+"CO2"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/P9O2KLE8PjOvoLREQ5PL39ZYKzOvRCMz2tAqUy8tMy9FQ91DXTM2v0jBUFPb0NrZ1gi3vHVBEVBOyUhJO1NbSUFbQUk7wT9BW8kfKKCkYAfkZkYj6dE2tIrVVvIw8lcCqoSodgaqdgYq///f2djDAgA)

Comment: You don't need a space between `print` and a `"` character, and the `CO2` variable could be named something shorter :)

Comment: @undergroundmonorail thanks

Comment: Since `i[1]` is guaranteed to be either `"H"` or a digit, you can save another byte with `if i[1]>"9"` (or replace `"9"` with any other character with an ascii value from 58 to 71)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 96*0.9 = 86.4

```
f=s=>`2C${(n=(s.match(/\d+(?!.*\d)/)[0]-2))>2?n/2:''}H${n+2} + ${1.5*n+1}O2 > ${n+2}H2O + ${n}CO2`
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
2r_'H/1=[i_((_2/1$+)@@]"+%dO2>%dH2O+%dCO2"e%
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2r_'H%2F1%3D%5Bi_((_2%2F1%24%2B)%40%40%5D%22%2B%25dO2%3E%25dH2O%2B%25dCO2%22e%25&input=C12H26)

To avoid special casing `CH4`, I don't use the first number at all, and only extract the number after the `H`. This gives the value of `2n+2`. The remaining values are then calculated based on that, and formatted.

Explanation:

```
2       Push leading 2 for output.
r       Get input.
_'H/    Copy and split at 'H.
1=      Take second part after split, this is 2n+2.
[       Start list.
  i       Convert string value to integer.
  _((     Copy and decrement twice, giving 2n.
  _2/     Copy and divide by 2, giving n.
  1$      Copy the 2n to the top.
  +       Add, to get 3n.
  )       Increment, giving 3n+1. We now have 2n+2, 2n, 3n+1 on stack.
  @@      Rotate top 3 entries twice, to get 3n+1, 2n+2, 2n.
]       Close list.
"+%dO2>%dH2O+%dCO2"
        Format string for output.
e%      "printf" operator.
```

Comment: `2r_[[~]W=_2/(3*)\_2-]"+%dO2>%dH2O+%dCO2"e%` saves a byte.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, (84 + 1) * 0.9 = 76.5

(+1 char for running with the `-n` flag)

My first Perl golf!

```perl
@x=(1,m/C(\d)/g);$n=$x[$#x];say"2$_ + ".(3*$n+1)."O2 > ".(($n*=2)+2)."H20 + ${n}CO2"
```

It's important that STDIN not contain a trailing newline. Example usage:

```perl
llama@llama:...code/perl/ppcg64412chemistry$ printf CH4 | perl -n chemistry.pl
2CH4 + 4O2 > 4H20 + 2CO2
```

Ungolfed-ish:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.0;

$_ = 'C3H8';
my @x = (1, m/C(\d)/g);
my $n = $x[$#x];
say "2$_ + ".(3*$n+1)."O2 > ".(($n*=2)+2)."H20 + ${n}CO2";
```

The lines

```perl
my @x = (1, m/C(\d)/g);
my $n = $x[$#x];
```

are fairly interesting here. `$#x` represents the "last populated index" of `@x` (and SE's syntax highlighting thinks it's a comment because it's dumb), so `$x[$#x]` will select the captured part of the `C(\d)` regex *if* it exists, or `1` otherwise. (Perl doesn't care that it'll be a string in all other cases except `1`; you can use numerical operators on strings just fine in Perl.)

Answer (score 2):

## , 64 * 0.9 = 57.6 bytes

```es
a=ïČ`H”[1],`2⦃ï} + ⦃a*1.5-2}O2 > ⦃a}H2O + ⦃a-2}CO2`
```

[Try it here (Firefox only)](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=CH4&code=a%3D%C3%AF%C4%8C%60H%E2%80%9D%5B1%5D%2C%602%E2%A6%83%C3%AF%7D%20%2B%20%E2%A6%83a*1.5-2%7DO2%20%3E%20%E2%A6%83a%7DH2O%20%2B%20%E2%A6%83a-2%7DCO2%60)

### Explanation

```
a=ïČ`H”[1],      // split input along H to get 2n+2
`  2⦃ï}          // 2C(n)H(2n+2) – this is the same as 2[input alkane's formula]
   + ⦃a*1.5-2}O2 // + 2(3n+1)O2
   > ⦃a}H2O      // > (2n+2)H2O
   + ⦃a-2}CO2    // + (2n)O2
`                // implicitly output the template string above
```

Answer (score 1):

### JS, 118 (106) bytes

```
x=prompt();y=x.replace("CH","C1H").match(/\d{1,}/g)[0];alert(2+x+" + "+(3*y+1)+"O2 > "+(2*y+2)+"H2O + "+(2*y)+"CO2");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 160 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){int n=1,t;std::cin.get();std::cin>>n;t=2*n;printf("2C");n-1&&printf("%i",n);printf("H%i + %iO2 > %iH2O + %iCO2",t+2,t+n+1,t+2,t);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBDoIwFET3nqKpgbQCJi0bQ6UbNt1xBlIq@Ql8CXxXxrNX1MhiMvMmz89z4ccOhxiPgH589OEK95WW0E32AEhs6gCFfH4m1ions1JfVR7wPAQSckdr0VCtT2jmZZNvguuGS4OFStP/kwDPUe6CS4BlLIFWM7uV0@0Xm1bznDK9BTP1W9K8YmxKd3kD)

A bit more that I expected. Reads first char and discards it, then reads int and outputs the result. Problem is with `n` being 1. I can't think of shorter way to output it.

Ungolfed

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n = 1, t;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin >> n;
    t = 2 * n;
    printf("2C");
    n - 1 && printf("%i", n);
    printf("H%i + %iO2 > %iH2O + %iCO2", t + 2, t + n + 1, t + 2, t);
}
```

Comment: Now works for CH4 [152 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYuxDoIwFEV3v6JBm7S2mNAwUVqHLmx8A0EkL4FHA28z@usVTXQ79@SePsa8nzocUzrCHJeValg2Wodu9gdAYnMHKOTjg6jJbnSrqh7wMg4k5H96j5aUI4cOr1Vh47oHd5Hx8gQNB6YYh9Ywz3ixC9N@RWhNpsqzwPp3NyGTUpMyGvMXadIo7TOl0JRv "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 113 bytes

```fs
let s=stdin.ReadLine()
float s.[1+s.IndexOf 'H'..]|>fun f->printf"2%s + %gO2 > %gH2O + %gCO2"s<|f*1.5-2.<|f<|f-2.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RKHYtrgkJTNPLyg1McUnMy9VQ5MrLSc/ESihF22oXaznmZeSWuGfpqDuoa6nF1tjl1aap5Cma1dQlJlXkqZkpFqsoK2gmu5vpGAHpDyM/MFcZ38jpWKbmjQtQz1TXSM9IAuIgIz//52NPSwA)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 96 * 0.9 = 86.4 bytes

```
s=input('');i=[sscanf(s,'C%dH'),1];n=i(1);fprintf('%s + %dO2 > %dH2O + %dCO2',s,3*n+1,2*n+2,2*n)
```

Fairly self explanatory. Takes an input string (need to wrap it in quote marks so MATLAB doesn't try to execute it!). Then converts the number between the C and the H in the input to decimal. The value 1 is appended as an array to the output of sscanf so that in the case `CH4` when we extract the first index in the array into `n` we get a 1 if there was no number between the C and H.
Then just prints out with the spaces following the formula in the question.

This should also work with **Octave** using the online interpreter [here](http://octave-online.net/).

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure/ClojureScript, 98*0.9 = 88.2 bytes

```
#(let[n(max 1(int((re-find #"C(.*)H"%)1)))m(* 2 n)](str "2"%" + "(inc(* 3 n))"O2 > "(+ 2 m)"H2O + "m"CO2"))
```

Creates an anonymous function.  Try it by going [here](http://clojurescript.net/) and entering `(def f #(let...))`, then `(f "C3H8")`.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 123 * 0.9 = 110.7 bytes

```
=="2"&A1&" + "&(3*MID(A1,FIND("H",A1)+1,9)/2-2)&"O2 > "&MID(A1,FIND("H",A1)+1,9)&"H2O + "&(MID(A1,FIND("H",A1)+1,9)-2)&"CO2"
```

If we could take CH4 input as C1H4, can be reduced to 122 * 0.9 = 109.8 bytes

```
="2"&A1&" + "&3*MID(A1,2,FIND("H",A1)-2)+1&"O2"&" > "&MID(A1,FIND("H",A1)+1,9)&"H2O + "&(MID(A1,FIND("H",A1)+1,9)-2)&"CO2"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 33 bytes

```
ṣ”HṪVµ2³”+2⁸_©+H“O2>”⁸“H2O+”®“CO2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGuZ6PNy5KuzQVqNDm4EcbaNHjTviD63U9njUMMffyA4oBBQAsj2M/LWBnEPrgGxnf6P///87e5gAAA)

The bonus doesn't help here.